# Turning off part of long running Entity Framework query conditionally

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

In my Asp.Net Web Api project, there's a GET method to fetch all processes. Process in my app is an entity to log various maintenence activities, it has many properties, e.g. beginning and end. Each processes can be handled by many users and so single Process can have many Handlings associated with it. Each handling also has begining and end timestamps. Recently I added "HandlingsLength" property to calculate for each process its handlings length. Unfortunately, adding this property made all requests targeting the method run almost twice as long..

Now, I'm looking for a way to improve the execution time of my method, either by complete rewrite, or by using some smart workaround. There are requests which doesn't mind waiting long for response, but there are also requests that don't need this property calculated and need to be fast too. My first idea was passing handlingsLength argument to my method and depending on its value HandlingsLength would be calculated or just set to null.

```
HandlingsLength = handlingsLength == null || handlingsLength == false ? null : grp.Where(ph => ph.ha.HandlingId > 0).Sum(h => DbFunctions.DiffMinutes(h.ha.StartedOn, h.ha.FinishedOn)) == null ? grp.Where(ph => ph.ha.HandlingId > 0).Sum(h => DbFunctions.DiffMinutes(h.ha.StartedOn, DateTime.Now)) : grp.Where(ph => ph.ha.HandlingId > 0).Sum(h => DbFunctions.DiffMinutes(h.ha.StartedOn, h.ha.FinishedOn))
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work, even if I pass handlingsLenght=null to indicate this property shouldn't be calculated, run time is more-less the same. Probably my linq statement is compiled to SQL at compilation so it doesn't know the value parameter provided on runtime. If there's a way to effectively 'turn off' this property at runtime, it's very welcome.

Here's complete body of my linq to entity statement:

```
items = (from p in db.JDE_Processes
                         join uuu in db.JDE_Users on p.FinishedBy equals uuu.UserId into finished
                         from fin in finished.DefaultIfEmpty()
                         join t in db.JDE_Tenants on p.TenantId equals t.TenantId
                         join u in db.JDE_Users on p.CreatedBy equals u.UserId
                         join at in db.JDE_ActionTypes on p.ActionTypeId equals at.ActionTypeId
                         join uu in db.JDE_Users on p.StartedBy equals uu.UserId into started
                         from star in started.DefaultIfEmpty()
                         join lsu in db.JDE_Users on p.LastStatusBy equals lsu.UserId into lastStatus
                         from lStat in lastStatus.DefaultIfEmpty()
                         join pl in db.JDE_Places on p.PlaceId equals pl.PlaceId
                         join comp in db.JDE_Components on p.ComponentId equals comp.ComponentId into comps
                         from components in comps.DefaultIfEmpty()
                         join s in db.JDE_Sets on pl.SetId equals s.SetId
                         join a in db.JDE_Areas on pl.AreaId equals a.AreaId
                         join h in db.JDE_Handlings on p.ProcessId equals h.ProcessId into hans
                         from ha in hans.DefaultIfEmpty()
                         where p.TenantId == TenantId && p.CreatedOn >= dFrom && p.CreatedOn <= dTo
                         group new { p, fin, t, u, at, started, lastStatus, lStat, pl, s, a, ha }
                         by new
                         {
                             p.ProcessId,
                             p.Description,
                             p.StartedOn,
                             p.StartedBy,
                             p.FinishedOn,
                             p.FinishedBy,
                             p.PlannedFinish,
                             p.PlannedStart,
                             p.PlaceId,
                             pl.SetId,
                             SetName = s.Name,
                             pl.AreaId,
                             AreaName = a.Name,
                             pl.Image,
                             p.Reason,
                             p.CreatedBy,
                             CreatedByName = u.Name + " " + u.Surname,
                             p.CreatedOn,
                             p.ActionTypeId,
                             p.Output,
                             p.InitialDiagnosis,
                             p.RepairActions,
                             p.TenantId,
                             p.MesId,
                             p.MesDate,
                             p.Comment,
                             TenantName = t.TenantName,
                             p.IsActive,
                             p.IsCompleted,
                             p.IsFrozen,
                             p.IsSuccessfull,
                             p.IsResurrected,
                             ActionTypeName = at.Name,
                             FinishedByName = fin.Name + " " + fin.Surname,
                             StartedByName = star.Name + " " + star.Surname,
                             PlaceName = pl.Name,
                             ComponentId = p.ComponentId,
                             ComponentName = components.Name,
                             LastStatus = p.LastStatus == null ? (ProcessStatus?)null : (ProcessStatus)p.LastStatus, // Nullable enums handled
                         p.LastStatusBy,
                             LastStatusByName = lStat.Name + " " + lStat.Surname,
                             p.LastStatusOn
                         } into grp
                         orderby grp.Key.CreatedOn descending
                         select new Process
                         {
                             ProcessId = grp.Key.ProcessId,
                             Description = grp.Key.Description,
                             StartedOn = grp.Key.StartedOn,
                             StartedBy = grp.Key.StartedBy,
                             StartedByName = grp.Key.StartedByName,
                             FinishedOn = grp.Key.FinishedOn,
                             FinishedBy = grp.Key.FinishedBy,
                             FinishedByName = grp.Key.FinishedByName,
                             ActionTypeId = grp.Key.ActionTypeId,
                             ActionTypeName = grp.Key.ActionTypeName,
                             IsActive = grp.Key.IsActive,
                             IsFrozen = grp.Key.IsFrozen,
                             IsCompleted = grp.Key.IsCompleted,
                             IsSuccessfull = grp.Key.IsSuccessfull,
                             PlaceId = grp.Key.PlaceId,
                             PlaceName = grp.Key.PlaceName,
                             PlaceImage = grp.Key.Image,
                             SetId = grp.Key.SetId,
                             SetName = grp.Key.SetName,
                             AreaId = grp.Key.AreaId,
                             AreaName = grp.Key.AreaName,
                             Output = grp.Key.Output,
                             TenantId = grp.Key.TenantId,
                             TenantName = grp.Key.TenantName,
                             CreatedOn = grp.Key.CreatedOn,
                             CreatedBy = grp.Key.CreatedBy,
                             CreatedByName = grp.Key.CreatedByName,
                             MesId = grp.Key.MesId,
                             InitialDiagnosis = grp.Key.InitialDiagnosis,
                             RepairActions = grp.Key.RepairActions,
                             Reason = grp.Key.Reason,
                             MesDate = grp.Key.MesDate,
                             Comment = grp.Key.Comment,
                             ComponentId = grp.Key.ComponentId,
                             ComponentName = grp.Key.ComponentName,
                             PlannedStart = grp.Key.PlannedStart,
                             PlannedFinish = grp.Key.PlannedFinish,
                             LastStatus = grp.Key.LastStatus,
                             LastStatusBy = grp.Key.LastStatusBy,
                             LastStatusByName = grp.Key.LastStatusByName,
                             LastStatusOn = grp.Key.LastStatusOn,
                             IsResurrected = grp.Key.IsResurrected,
                             OpenHandlings = grp.Where(ph => ph.ha.HandlingId > 0 && (ph.ha.IsCompleted == null || ph.ha.IsCompleted == false)).Count(),
                             AllHandlings = grp.Where(ph => ph.ha.HandlingId > 0).Count(),
                             AssignedUsers = (from pras in db.JDE_ProcessAssigns
                                              join uu in db.JDE_Users on pras.UserId equals uu.UserId
                                              where pras.ProcessId == grp.Key.ProcessId
                                              select uu.Name + " " + uu.Surname),
                             GivenTime = givenTime == null || givenTime == false ? 0 : (from prac in db.JDE_ProcessActions
                                                                                        join a in db.JDE_Actions on prac.ActionId equals a.ActionId
                                                                                        where prac.ProcessId == grp.Key.ProcessId
                                                                                        select a.GivenTime).Sum(),
                             FinishRate = finishRate == null || finishRate == false ? 0 : db.JDE_ProcessActions.Count(i => i.ProcessId == grp.Key.ProcessId)==0 
                                                                                        ? 100 : (((float)db.JDE_ProcessActions.Count(i => i.ProcessId == grp.Key.ProcessId && i.IsChecked == true)
                                                                                        / (float)db.JDE_ProcessActions.Count(i => i.ProcessId == grp.Key.ProcessId))*100),
                             HasAttachments = db.JDE_FileAssigns.Any(f => f.ProcessId == grp.Key.ProcessId),
                             HandlingsLength = handlingsLength == null || handlingsLength == false ? null : grp.Where(ph => ph.ha.HandlingId > 0).Sum(h => DbFunctions.DiffMinutes(h.ha.StartedOn, h.ha.FinishedOn)) == null ? grp.Where(ph => ph.ha.HandlingId > 0).Sum(h => DbFunctions.DiffMinutes(h.ha.StartedOn, DateTime.Now)) : grp.Where(ph => ph.ha.HandlingId > 0).Sum(h => DbFunctions.DiffMinutes(h.ha.StartedOn, h.ha.FinishedOn))
                         });
```

Comment: Do you really need to perform this whole query in one go? Not only is it slow but (no offence meant) it looks like a nightmare to maintain and difficult to debug. Perhaps breaking up your requests in pieces and load details separately?

Comment: Your query looks like you are trying to fix bad JOIN with GroupBy because of generating duplicates.

Comment: @Xerillio Don't worry, I realize it's a bit of a nightmare This is what you end up with when you keep throwing more and more properties to fetch with no time to refactor your code.. I could probably load things separately, but later I'd have to glue them back together to form single response (assuming you meant separating at back end site). I need all the fields in 1 object as I later put it as DataGridView source. Could you elaborate a bit on how you'd break the code (might be on simpler example) and put it back together to compose single response? Or provide a link to example elsewhere

Comment: @robs23 I was thinking about the frontend requesting details separately. E.g. load all processes first without joining on the user table. Then afterwards the client requests details for all users associated with (created by, finished by...). Of course whether this is a feasible solution depends on your application.

Comment: @Xerillio Yep, seems to be feasible, though a bit time consuming as this API need to work with desktop and mobile apps.. And I probably forgot to mention, the long time to response is NOT caused by a lot of data being send in single response - I did some testing and response time doesn't change much whether I send 100 / 200 or 300 records. So it seems it's entirely calculation-related problem in Web Api app. I think I'll try to work directly on this API method first and see how much I can improve the time and share my findings back here

Comment: @Svyatoslav Danyliv The grouping was implemented to get OpenHandlings /AllHandlings values, which are in one-to-many relation with Process (1 Process might have many Handlings). At the time it seemed to be good solution, but admittedly it introduced a lot of complexity to the code..

Comment: AssignedUsers also one-to-many. So just try without grouping.

Comment: You're totally right. Just changed HandlingsLength to `HandlingsLength = (from has in db.JDE_Handlings
                                                    where has.ProcessId == grp.Key.ProcessId
                                                    select has.FinishedOn == null ? System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlFunctions.DateDiff("n", has.StartedOn, has.FinishedOn).Value : System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlFunctions.DateDiff("n", has.StartedOn, has.FinishedOn).Value).Sum()` and see around 40% request processing boost :)

Comment: Honestly speaking I didn't expect that, I think it works a bit like SQL subquery, and I thought those are slower comparing to aggregations.. Probably I could reduce processing time by another X% if I got rid of this grouping